# how do I deploy an Angular Project to Github Pages?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, github-pages, angular-cli-ghpages

I have been following along with the Angular Documentation for [building your first app](https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app)

I want to deploy the application as it is, but when using CLI to run `ng deploy` I receive an error that reads as the following

[Terminal responses from running ng deploy | error is 'NOT SUPPORTED: keyword"id", use "$id" for schemaID'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56V8h.png)

The app Runs correctly locally, but is not building on GH pages.
[Repo Link](https://github.com/wloverde/AngularJS-TavernCrawl)

I have read over the documentation on the NPM page for angular-cli-ghpages

When running `ng add angular-cli-ghpages` is when I receive the "NOT SUPPORTED" response.

Afterwards, I attempted to manually insert the Configuration into the angular.json file as such:

```
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "angular-cli-ghpages:deploy",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "https://wloverde.github.io/AngularJS-TavernCrawl/",
            "name": "wloverde",
            "email": "w.andrew.loverde@gmail.com"
          }
        },
```

when this didn't work I attempted to run `$ npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir=dist/Angular-js-tavern-crawl`
it stated that it successfully published, but doesn't render anything onto the page.

I am deploying the site from the gh-pages branch created from running the npx CLI

Comment: The default build workflow uses the static site generator Jekyll, which in your case doesn't hurt, but also doesn't help; you can add an empty `.nojekyll` file to the gh-pages branch to prevent Jekyll from running.

Comment: Secondly, I think almost everything works, and your JS files are uploaded, but with the wrong path: they are expected at `https://wloverde.github.io/runtime.eb49bcca2eb5b717.js`, but really live at `https://wloverde.github.io/AngularJS-TavernCrawl/runtime.eb49bcca2eb5b717.js` (missing the repository name). You have to update your relative links to include the repository name.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I did see those console log messages as well! I just wasn't sure what to make of the information! 

I added the Repo name to my angular.json file as such: 
```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "configurations": {
      "production": {
        "baseHref": "/your-repo-name/",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This resolved my issue and now it properly deploys! Thank you